# How to make UI methods wait for an asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have two arrays (groupIDs, groupNames) I need to fill with variables received from certain URLs which is done inside a subclass extending AsyncTask as otherwise, it results in a NetworkOnMainThreadException error. Problem is I need to make sure those two arrays are filled before `initRecyclerView();` is called in UI thread.

How can I make sure my code waits for async to finish before executing `initRecyclerView();`?

```
public class GroupPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "RecycleViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Integer> groupIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<>();

    private class groupPageConnect extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            try{
                System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
                getGroups();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Oops!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void getGroups() throws Exception{
        String url = "http://obsco.me/obsco/api/v1.0/users/12345671";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code  for IDs: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONArray allContainingArray = reader.getJSONArray("users");
        JSONObject userJSON  = (JSONObject) allContainingArray.get(0);
        JSONArray temp = userJSON.getJSONArray("groups");

        Log.d(TAG, "initializing");
        for (int x = 0; x < temp.length(); x++){
            //System.out.println(temp.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"));
            groupIDs.add(temp.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id"));
            System.out.println(groupIDs.size() );
            System.out.println(groupIDs.get(x));
            //groupNames.add("Dummy");

            url = "http://obsco.me/obsco/api/v1.0/groupname/" + groupIDs.get(x);
            System.out.println("ar1");
            obj = new URL(url);
            System.out.println("ar2");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code  for IDs: " + responseCode);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            reader = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            System.out.println(reader.getString("name"));
            groupNames.add(reader.getString("name"));
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_page);
        Log.d(TAG, "started");
        try {
            groupPageInit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void groupPageInit() throws Exception{
        new groupPageConnect().execute();
        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initializingRecyclerView");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter( this, groupIDs, groupNames);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `getGroups()` you can use `runOnUiThread()`.

Example:

```
getGroups();
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Logic that you want to execute on main thread
                        initRecyclerView();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call initRecyclerView() method on onPostExecute(result)method. An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by  4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.onPostExecute(Result) invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes.

```
private class groupPageConnect extends AsyncTask<Object,void,String> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
           //put your code here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             //call what you want to update
                        initRecyclerView();

            // dismiss progress dialog here
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // start progress dialog here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
         // progress update here}
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onPostExecute.

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.[task goes through 4 steps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#the-4-steps)

Please pay attention that loading of data from network through AsyncTask may be cause of memory leaks .

Comment: How so? How can I make sure there are no memory leaks?

Comment: Try adding logs to onCreate and onDestroy:
    Log.d("GroupPage", "onCreate: " + String.valueOf(GroupPage.this));



Add long work emulation to doInBackground:
            Log.d("GroupPage", "start: " + String.valueOf(GroupPage.this));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("GroupPage", "end: " + String.valueOf(GroupPage.this));



Turn phone several times. You can see that after onDestroy a link to GroupPage is available.